# How to construct a linear inequality matrix.

Tags: matrices, inequality

I am wondering how exactly these two matrices ([source (p.16)](http://drona.csa.iisc.ac.in/~uday//e0358/poly_intro.pdf)) were constructed from the set of affine inequalities:

$$
\begin{align}
  i &\geq 0\\
  j &\geq 0\\
  −i + N − 1 &\geq 0\\
  −j + N − 1 &\geq 0
\end{align}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
D=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
−1 & 0 & 1 & −1 \\
0 & −1 & 1 & −1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  i\\
  j\\
  N\\
  1
\end{bmatrix}
\geq 0
$$

I can't tell how the cells in the first matrix got there.

---

In trying to understand *affine inequalities* and *polytopes*, I have these definitions:

> A polytope is defined as:
>
> $$S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \leq b \}$$
>   $$S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax + b \geq 0 \}$$
>
> where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
>
> The elements of $A$ and $b$ can be taken as integers if we want a $\mathbb{Z}$-polytope.
>
> Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in R$ be given.
>
> - The set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid a^T x = b\}$ is called a hyperplane.
> - The set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid a^T x \leq b\}$ is called a half-space.
>
> A polyhedron $P \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded if there exists a constant $K$
>   such that $|x_i| < K\ \forall x \in P, \forall i \in [1, n]$.
>
> A polytope is a bounded polyhedron.
>
> The image of a polytope $P$ under an affine map $π:x \mapsto Ax + b$ is also a polytope.
>
> You can define a polytope by either (1) affine inequalities or (2) a convex hull.

So in there I see $Ax + b \geq 0$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. That seems similar to the matrix above (correct me if I'm wrong), where $A$ is the first matrix and $b$ is the second (not sure where $x$ is). Trying to get an understanding of how the affine inequality equation is converted into matrix form. Not sure what field goes where.